# Set a reset button to clear a specific single input of type text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following:

```
<div id="section1">
 <label> Label 1 </label>
 <br>
 <input type="text" id="input_section1">
 <button type="reset" class="clear"></button>
</div>
```

This is how the html must remain structured. I have other divs on the page that are the same as the above (called #section2, #section3 etc), and none of the inputs are within a form.

So what I want is the button to reset the specific input it is associated with; in the case above, the input '#input_section1'.

At the moment when I click the reset button it is clearing every input on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following jquery code using `.siblings()`:

```
$(document).on('click','.clear',function(){
    $(this).siblings( "input" ).val('');
});
```

This will find the `input type sibling` of the current clicked element and reset it.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykqyhovb/)

Comment: this works great but it is refreshing the page for me, is there a way to do this without having the page refresh?

Comment: It would not refresh the page, as you can see in the fiddle itself. I think the problem is some thing else.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution:

```
<input type="button" onClick="document.getElementById('input_secion1').value='';">
```

This should do what you are asking for.